# MySQL LIMIT x,y performance huge difference on 2 machine

Tags: mysql, performance

I have a query in an InnoDb `item` table which contains 400k records (only...). I need to page the result for the presentation layer (60 per page) so I use `LIMIT` with values depending on the page to display.

The query is (the `110000` offset is just an example):

```
SELECT i.id, sale_type, property_type, title, property_name, latitude,
       longitude,street_number, street_name, post_code,picture, url,
       score, dw_id, post_date
FROM item i WHERE picture IS NOT NULL AND picture != ''
AND sale_type = 0
ORDER BY score DESC  LIMIT 110000, 60;
```

Running this query on my machine takes about 1s.
Running this query on our test server is 45-50s.

EXPLAIN are both the same:

```
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+-----------+---------+------+--------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | type  | possible_keys | key       | key_len | ref  | rows   | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+-----------+---------+------+--------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | i     | index | NULL          | IDX_SCORE | 5       | NULL | 110060 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+-----------+---------+------+--------+-------------+
```

The only configuration difference when query `show variables` are:

- `innodb_use_native_aio`. It is enabled on the Test server, not on my machine. I tried disabling it and I don't see any significant change
- `innodb_buffer_pool_size` 1G on Test server, 2G on my machine

Test server has 2Gb of ram, 2 core CPU:

- mysqld uses > 65% of RAM at all time, but only increase 1-2% running above query
- mysqld uses 14% of CPU while running the above query, none when idle

My local machine has 8Gb, 8 core CPU:

- mysqld uses 28% of RAM at all time, and doesn't really increase while running the above query (or for a so short time I can see it)
- mysqld uses 48% of CPU while running the above query, none when idle

Where and what can I do to have the same performance on the Test server? Is the RAM and/or CPU too low?

**UPDATE**

I have setup a new Test server with the same specs but 8G of RAM and 4 core CPU and the performance just jumped to values similar to my machine. The original server didn't seem to use all of the RAM/CPU, why are performance so worse?

Comment: I think Bill answered it pretty well, but in addition to that, I think you would be a lot better off preventing the `picture` column from being either `NULL` or `''` (empty).  During entry, you should probably set it to `NULL` if it's empty, and thereby avoid having to perform the `AND` above.

Comment: @pickypg Thanks that's a great idea I should have thought too. We can easily do that in our code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the surest ways to kill performance is to make MySQL scan an index that doesn't fit in memory.  So during a query, it has to load part of the index into the buffer pool, then evict that part and load the other part of the index.  Causing churn in the buffer pool like this during a query will cause a lot of I/O load, and that makes it very slow.  Disk I/O is about 100,000 times slower than RAM.

So there's a big difference between 1GB of buffer pool and 2GB of buffer pool, if your index is, say 1.5GB.

Another tip:  you really don't want to use `LIMIT 110000, 60`.  That causes MySQL to read 110000 rows from the buffer pool (possibly loading them from disk if necessary) just to discard them.  There are other ways to page through result sets much more efficiently.

See articles such as [Optimized Pagination using MySQL](http://www.xarg.org/2011/10/optimized-pagination-using-mysql/).

Comment: Thanks. I will look in greater details the link but at first look it seems this is for static SQL. My SQL above is one among so many (the SQL is for a search form that have many options, some being ranges of values)... at first look :)